# Docker with ubtuntu:trusty and installing python-dev

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, apt-get

Thanks for taking a look at this. I created a docker image for ssh using https://github.com/kartoza/docker-ssh

Only difference is I used ubuntu:trusty.

After this I started the container and ssh'd into the container then I tried to install python and I  get the following:

```
root@a20f46f358b3:/script/docker/ubuntu-trusty# sudo apt-get -qq -y --no- 
install-recommends install python-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@a20f46f358b3:/peloton/peloton/script/docker/ubuntu-trusty# sudo apt-get  
install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-dev : Depends: libpython-dev (= 2.7.5-5ubuntu3) but it is not going 
to be installed
          Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.5-1~) but it is not going to be 
installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Should I use a different image for creating the container?

There are no held packages, I verified by executing and no output.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Any ideas on what I could do to resolve this issue? Many thanks for the guidance.

regards,
~Ash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using ubuntu:16.04 and that worked for me. I put the following in my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
```

Additionally, I used the following to run ssh server
https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

Hope this helps anyone else running into this issue.

Regards,
~Ash

Answer (score 2):

Try in Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and check [dependecies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-dev)

```
apt-get install -f python2.7-dev
```

Comment: you should (almost) never run `apt-get upgrade` in a dockerfile, and you shouldn't use `sudo` either

Comment: Hi @anthony .. thanks for the note, but can you share why you should never run `apt-get upgrade`  in Dockerfile. Is that because that should be part of starting the container?

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` will ~usually cause your resulting docker image to ~double in size as every package will be replicated in several layers.  Your best bet is to usually `docker pull` before building so you have an up-to-date base image (and rely on that to have up-to-date packages).  The actual bug in the linked dockerfile is they have `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in separate layers causing layer caching issues.